# How can I ensure a StackLayout is at least a minimum height?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried this in my code.

```
<StackLayout 
   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
   Spacing="0" 
   MinimumHeightRequest="50">
   <StackLayout Margin="20, 6, 20, 8" 
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
      Spacing="0">
      <Label Text="ABC" 
         HorizontalOptions="Start" 
         VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
   </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

But with small text such as ABC then the height is not equal to 50. Is there some way I can ensure the height is a minimum of 50?

Comment: Did you try to use properties like Microsoft does? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout

Comment: what about if you put the StackLayout into a grid ?

Comment: @Alan2 if i understand you correctly, you want the label to be expandable ? using the LineBreakMode property what do you think about this : **<StackLayout> <Label Text="ABC" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/> <Label Text="Nunc ut augue rhoncus, ultrices nulla quis, ultricies erat. Aenean aliquet turpis a leo egestas scelerisque." LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/> </StackLayout>**

Comment: Do you want the StackLayout to be 50-points tall, or do you want the Label inside of the StackLayout to be 50-points tall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would try something like that:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="50"/>
</Grid>
```

I'm doing that in my application, and it works fine. You set the `RowDefinition` to `Auto`, then, it is going to fit exactly your HeightRequest.

Answer (score 5):

Relaying what ShawnCastrianni.5092 on the following [forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66049/does-minimumheightrequest-work-at-all)

After reading the remarks in the API docs, I see this:

> "MinimumHeightRequest is used to override the results of a call to
>   VisualElement.GetSizeRequest (double, double) by setting the minimum
>   height property. This causes overflow handling to shrink this element
>   to its minimum height before elements who do not have a minimum size
>   set."
>
> I guess that matches what you said Jason. Therefore, I think everybody
>   will be thrown off by the name MinimumHeightRequest. I would prefer it
>   say **OverflowHeightRequest** to avoid any confusion.

The name itself is misleading. You'll have to create a custom solution to fix your issue

Comment: Would it be possible to add to that layout a grid such that the left hand side of the grid was a minimal width, size 50 vertical boxview and the right hand side was the Label area.  If so then an answer that showed that would be okay if it worked.

Comment: @Alan2 You actually can, just make sure you specify *  <RowDefinition Height="2*" />

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set `HeightRequest=50` and measure height of your label text. Use the ITextMeter from [this source](https://gist.github.com/alexrainman/82b00160ab32bef9e69dee6d460f44fa), and if text height is more than 50, then set HeightRequest to text height.