# Xamarin : How to set the height request for frame when having no child inside it

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

```
<Frame
Grid.Row="1"
Style="{StaticResource frameStyle}">
<stacklayout "Not Visible" />
</frame>
```

How to set minimum height request to 20 since minimium height request not working

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to place it into `Grid` , and set the row height as `Auto` ,than you can define the request height on the Frame .

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Frame Grid.Row="0" />
</Grid>
```

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52104484/8187800 .